# Why particles-js does not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

First I see the content, then I see the particles-js. I want to make sure that I see the particles-js and simultaneously at the same time.
I use materialize CSS
Code:

```
<div class="page-wrapper"> <div class="content">.... </div> </div>
<div id="particles-js"> </div>
<!-- Particles JS  -->
<script > .... </script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want Particles JS to be up and running as soon as the page loads?

Comment: @phuzi no . I want to make sure that the content is in the first place, and the particles-js, as the background .

Comment: It'd be great to have an snippet

Comment: @AminevTimur ah, so you want particles to fill the background of the page not just the space below the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your styles are broken or missing

```js
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/demo/particles.json', function() {
  //callback
});
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.my-content {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-content">
  my content
</div>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```